# Keep labels of merged variables only - Stata

Tags: label, stata

I have a database `A`. I want to merge it with **a few variables** from database `B` (which has hundreds of variables). All variables in `B` have labels. So, if I do:

```
use A.dta
merge 1:1 id using B.dta, keepusing(var1 var2)
```

I get **all value labels** from `B` copied into `A`.

If I do instead:

```
merge 1:1 id using B.dta, keepusing(var1 var2) nolabel
```

`var1` and `var2` have no labels in `A`.

There seems to be no option in `merge` which allows for a solution in between (i.e. to copy only the value labels of the merged ones).

A workaround would be to run:

```
labelbook, problems
label drop `r(notused)'
```

after the first method. Yet, this needs to be run every time a merge is done (and I am merging many many times). It can also be quite slow (dataset `B` has many many variables).

Another option would be to create a temporary dataset "B-minus" containing only the variables and value labels I want, and merge from it. But this also entails running the same time-consuming code above, so it's no different.

Is there a "better" way to achieve this?

---

**MCVE:**

```
webuse voter, clear
label list // shows two variables with value labels (candidat and inc)
drop candidat inc
label drop candidat inc2 // we drop all value labels
merge 1:1 pop frac using http://www.stata-press.com/data/r14/voter, nogen keepusing(candidat)
label list // instead of having only the candidat label, we also have inc
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no such an option in `merge` but you could simply use [macro list manipulation](https://www.stata.com/manuals/pmacrolists.pdf):

```
webuse voter, clear

label list // shows two variables with value labels (candidat and inc)
drop candidat inc
label drop candidat inc2 // we drop all value labels

local labkeep candidat // define which labels you want to keep   

merge 1:1 pop frac using http://www.stata-press.com/data/r14/voter, nogen keepusing(candidat)

quietly label dir
local secondary "`r(names)'"
display "`secondary'"

local newlabels :  list secondary - labkeep
display "`newlabels'"
label drop `newlabels'

label list
```

Comment: Thanks. This is fine in the trivial example of one merge with two labels (which is why the MCVE is not very useful here). In my case however, I'm merging many times (around 120), adding more labels to keep every iteration. To automate which labels to keep, I would still require to run `labelbook`, as the name of labels can be unintuitive. I just need something like `merge ... , merge_lab_only`, where merge keeps merged labels only! It's amazing the command does not include such option.

Comment: You can create a wrapper program then for `merge`. In this way you can simply run everything in one line. But do not expect speed gains. This is a matter of convenience and even if `merge` had such an option it wouldn't make much difference speed-wise.

Comment: So it seems the way Stata handles variables and labels makes it actually impossible to achieve what I want in a speedy way (which probably explains the odd behaviour of copying all labels when merging, at the benefit of faster merging).

Comment: Another option is to try the `nolabels` option for `merge`. Then you could create a loop to write whatever labels you want in the final dataset.

Comment: I found an alternative method. See my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

**Update**: Not using preserve/restore (thanks @Pearly Spencer for highlighting this) further improves the speed of the method. To see old code with preserve/restore, see [the older versions of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51723859/revisions).

---

I think I found a faster method to solve the problem (at least judging by results using `timer on`, `timer off`).

So, to recap, the current, slow approach is to merge databases, and then drop all unused labels using

```
labelbook, problems
label drop `r(notused)'
```

An alternative and faster method is to **load a smaller dataset** using only the needed variables. This will only contain the labels of selected variables. Then, merge this smaller database with the original one. Importantly, the merge direction is reversed! This way we eliminate the need for preserve/restore, which as @Pearly Spencer suggested, can slow down things a bit, particularly in larger datasets.

In terms of my original example, the code would be:

```
*** Open and work with dataset A ***

use A.dta // load original dataset
... // do stuff with it (added just for generality)
save A_final.dta // name of final dataset

*** Load dataset B with subset of needed variables only ***

use id var1 var2 using B.dta, clear // this loads id (needed for merging), var1 and var2 and their labels only!

*** Merge modified A dataset into smaller B dataset ***

merge 1:1 id using A_final.dta, keep(using match) // we do not specify any variables to load, as all those in A_final.dta needed) IMPORTANT: if we want to keep all observations of the original dataset (A, which is the one being merged into B), we need to use "using" rather than "master" in the "keep()" option.
save A_final.dta, replace // Create final version of A. Done!
```

That's it! I'm not sure this is the optimal solution, but in my case, where I am merging many datasets which have hundreds of variables, it is way faster.

---

The code in terms of the MCVE would be:

```
*** Open original dataset and work with it ***

webuse voter, clear
label list // shows two variables with value labels (candidat and inc)
drop candidat inc
label drop candidat inc2 // we drop all value labels
save final.dta

*** Create temporary dataset ***

use pop frac candidat using http://www.stata-press.com/data/r14/voter, clear // this is key. Only load needed variables!

*** Merge temporary dataset with original one ***

merge 1:1 pop frac using final.dta, nogen
label list // we only have the "candidat" label! Success!
save final.dta, replace
```

Comment: Well, you already mentioned this in your original question. Note that when working with 'real' datasets `preserve` and `restore` have the potential to introduce considerable overhead.

Comment: @PearlySpencer What I meant there was to run `use B.dta`, then `keep id var1 var`, and then delete labels with the two commands. In that sense, that is just as the other method. I was not aware of the `use <varlist> using B.dta` syntax, and that this loads only a subset of labels. What do you mean by overhead?

Comment: Speed taxing. `preserve` / `restore' are notoriously slow with large datasets. Speed will depend on your use case i guess.

Comment: @PearlySpencer mmm, it's even faster without preserve/restore, by also saving the working dataset and then reverse the direction of the merge! Will update the answer.

Comment: @PearlySpencer Updated. Much simpler code now. Thanks!